# event handlers of elements inside label getting executed even after using stopPropagation

Tags: jquery, css

I have few elements(like input, paragraph, radiobutton any element) embeded inside label. The parent of this label is div tag.
Applied event handlers for all the elements inside label and for parent div except the label tag. Applied stopPropagation also in all the event handlers. But when I click on any of the element inside label then respective event handler is being called and since stopPropagation is there, it is restricting parent event handler to be called. Till here it is fine. But the issue is it is also calling the event handlers of its siblings.

```
 <div class="scroll-content-item" data-pid="1773">
      <label>   
         <span class="custom">Custom</span>
         <input type="text" class="text custom_width" id="cust_width" value="960"/> 
         <p class="para"> This is test para</p>
      </label>
  </div>
```

### jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.para').click(function(event) {
        alert("paragraph event ");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.custom_width').click(function(event) {

        alert("input custom width event ");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });



    $('.scroll-content-item').click(function(event) {
        alert("parent div event ");
        event.stopPropagation();
    });

});​
```

When I click on paragraph, its event handler and handler of input type is also getting called. When I click on span with class custom, since it doesn't have event handler, parent is getting called first and later input type handler is getting called.

The question you may ask like what is the purpose of embedding p, input and all those inside label. We are using custom `input type="file"`  we are overlaying label data on input type file, but `onclick` on label input type file has to be triggered. For the same I am embedding elements inside label

Just want to know why the two event handlers are getting called even though I am using `stopPropagation`.

For reference I created jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/x7xQg/29/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

Adding a `return false;` to your event handler solves it.

Also add `event.preventDefault();` to cover all browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7xQg/30/

Comment: Thank for the response. Ya it works by adding return false and some how I removed elements inside label and full filled my requirement. But just want to know why it is calling siblings event handlers too. Then what is the purpose of adding event.stopPropagation.

Comment: Using preventDefault also serverd my requirement. But like anchor tag is there any default behaviour for labels too?